# Using WPF background from resource dictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml

My WPF application has several windows and I want to use the same background image for all of them.  I've defined the bitmap and image brush in a resource dictionary as follows.

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="BackgroundImage" UriSource="/Resources/BackPlate.png"/>
<ImageBrush x:Key="BackgroundBrush" ImageSource="{StaticResource BackgroundImage}" TileMode="Tile" ViewportUnits="Absolute" Viewport="0,0,128,128"/>
```

When I set the background property in the Window description, the background changes successfully in Visual Studio, but when I run the application, I get a parsing exception, I assume because the window resources haven't actually been read yet?

```
<Window x:Class="MyApp.Test"
...
    Background="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}">
<Window.Resources>
...
```

Is there another way to specify the background after the resources have been read?  I've tried the Window.Background approach, but I can't figure out how to get it to work w/o specifying the whole image brush definition.

```
 <Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ?>
</Window.Background>
```

Is there a way to specify the image brush by reference when using this approach?

Comment: Have you tried a [Style Template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa969824(v=vs.110).aspx) with the background added to it to be inherited to each instance? What's the exception you get?

Comment: The exception is "A first chance exception of type 'System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in PresentationFramework.dll

Additional information: 'Provide value on 'System.Windows.StaticResourceExtension' threw an exception.' Line number '5' and line position '35'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work provided that you merge the `ResourceDictionary` into your `App.xaml` file:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="YourResourceDictionary.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```